# How can i tell if my phone has ever been rooted?

Tags: rooting, factory-reset, unrooting

Banking apps can be not running when they think the phone is not safe even the phone is “not” rooted .

And factory reset or OTA update after rooting can make root access botched. Just like unrooting phone. So root checker apps can’t detect rooting after factory reset.

Then can i tell whether my phone has ever been rooted before factory reset without checking knox?
(Cuz broken knox doesnt necessarily mean rooting.)

My phone is reset . Root checking apps say its not rooted. But banking apps dont work.

Is thery any way to check..?

Comment: Factory reset does normally not remove root. Root my not work anymore because of missing app but the system partition is still modified and thus a banking app will refuse to work as the device state is not genuine. Only installing a full firmware may restore the original state (not sure about Samsung phone as rooting shout permanently trigger the fuse that disables Knox).

Comment: Yes,,, so i just want to know system partition has ever been modified..  Honestly… I am worrying malware app could root my phone . Cuz my phone got factory reset by malware app suddenly. So what i have now is reset phone .Thats why i want to know if my phone was rooted.. i used data recovery program after reset So i think thats maybe reason banking apps dont run now . But not sure the name of program so cant check if that programs have rooting feature.So i just want to know if my phone has ever been rooted before reset. worrying i cant even sleep i dont usethat phone anymore just want to check